# WPF interoperability - how can I get the including Form object from the WPF control?

Tags: wpf, winforms, user-controls

I have a form of Form1 class and a WPF user control inside it (inside ElementHost). How can I get the Form1 object from this control's code-behind?

Here is the code:

```
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for UserControl1.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
{

    public UserControl1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
         // I'd like to access the form here
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you saying, You've put a WPF control inside a WinForm Form ?

Comment: please provide some code about what you have tried and you are sure your wpf `Usercontrol` is inside your form?

Comment: I would definitely like to see the code.

Comment: Hosting a WPF control inside Winforms is possible http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742215.aspx

Comment: Basically you can't unless you find a way to pass the WinForms control to your usercontrol. OOPs fundamentals will apply.